# Countries not producing beer

Tags: breweries

It seems like it's possible to find beer from almost every corner of the world today. What are the countries without any national brands / breweries?

Comment: This seems too broad for this format.  There's a Wikipedia article compiling information on countries that *do* have national brands/breweries http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_and_breweries_by_region

Comment: Not really. The negation makes the scope it sufficiently narrow. Without the negation, it would be too broad.

Comment: I agree with @SantaC. There shouldn't be more than 20-30 countries that fit this description and they should all fall into 2-3 neat categories.

Comment: 20-30 .. humhum ... I would have bet much less than that ...

Comment: Does Antarctica count; it's not a country, but still?

Answer (score 6):

While not exhaustive, countries that observe strict Islamic law, [such as Iran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_in_Iran), do not allow the production of alcoholic beverages.

In the case of Iran, there are some companies that produce non-alcoholic beer, but none that produce a traditional alcoholic beer.